# Qual o limite de espaço de cada Base de dados no mysql

Tags: mysql

Vejo que alguns `SGBD's` tem um limite de espaço definido para cada Base de dados. Como no caso da versão Express do SQL Server que disponibiliza `10GB` para cada Base. Gostaria de saber se no `MySql` tem algum limite, e se um banco pesado pode interferir muito em minha aplicação.

Estou com essa duvida pois estou pensando em adicionar mais dados em uma Base que tenho para minha analise no `QlikView` ficar mais completa. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL é mais complicado de ser avaliado neste sentido que outros SGBDs pois o motor de armazenamento influencia nas capacidades do banco.

Por exemplo, o MySQL em sí não possui limite de tabelas, sendo limitado pelo sistema de arquivos escolhido. Porém, se você utilizar InnoDB como motor de armazenamento, ele é limitado em 4 bilhões de tabelas (inteiro sem sinal de 32 bits).

No caso do tamanho das tabelas, utilizando um sistema de arquivos moderno, a limitação é um bocado absurda: utilizando MyISAM, você pode ter tabela de até 256TB, se o sistema de arquivos suportar (hoje, qualquer FS moderno - aka NTFS, ext4, xfs, etc - suporta pelo menos 2TB, sendo comum eles suportarem os 256TB).

Enfim, no geral, não há muito com o que se preocupar desde que você não trabalhe no LHC, que gera TB de dados diariamente.

O mais importante, é utilizar as versões mais modernas tanto do Sistema Operacional, quanto do Sistema de Arquivos, quanto do SGBD (e obviamente utilizar o SGBD mais apropriado para a tarefa).

Mais detalhes sobre os limites do MySQL, veja na documentação oficial:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limits.html

Answer (score 3):

É uma resposta bem complicada por que depende muito do tipo de registro que você vai adicionar, os tamanhos de campos e mais um monte de coisas que podem interferir neste espaço ocupado no MySql.

Neste link você pode dar uma estudada:

http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL